# Error when accessing keychain with Firebase iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain, ios10

I'm having issues with keychain on iOS 10 devices. Failed to retrieve saved users, only happens with iOS 10 users, authentication is with Firebase. This is the error:

> Error loading saved user when starting up: Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17995 "An error occurred when accessing the keychain. The @c NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the @c NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred when accessing the keychain. The @c NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the @c NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered, error_name=ERROR_KEYCHAIN_ERROR, NSLocalizedFailureReason=SecItemCopyMatching (0)}

Comment: Are you trying this on an actual device or in the simulator? There is a Keychain bug with the iOS 10 simulator. The error code is different, but it might still be related: https://openradar.appspot.com/27844971

Comment: @JordanBondo On the device

Comment: did you solve this? I seem to be having the same issue

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As mentioned in the link of the first answer there is a workaround:

1. Go to your *.xcodeproj
2. Go to the tab "Capabilities"
3. Activate "Keychain Sharing"

Btw, is there an issue tracker for xcode?

Comment: My keychain is enabled, but I'm still getting the same error as OP, does anyone know where `@c NSError.userInfo dictionary` is? I have no idea how to even check that.

Comment: This may be a glitch when using a simulator as pointet out in this github comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/818#issuecomment-587928935

Comment: This doesn't work. Are you leaving some other important detail out?

Comment: @metamonkey This is the important detail left out!

Answer (score 1):

Building on @bash0ne's answer:

First, do what @bash0ne said, namely (modified for the newer version of Xcode):

- Go to your app target
- Go to the tab "Signing & Capabilities"
- Click the plus in the top right corner
- Search "Keychain Sharing" and select it to activate it

Then, add a Keychain group. To do so, in Signing & Capabilities (same section as before) scroll to the "Keychain Sharing" section. There is a table for "Keychain Groups," and you can add to this table.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56706413/swift-cross-app-authentication-is-not-working) says, the keychain group needs to have this format:

`<TEAM_ID>.<APP_NAME>.<GROUP_NAME>`

If you click "+", Xcode adds the default group, and the default that Xcode added worked for me.

Final, somewhat separate note. Users in the comments asked how to check "userInfo" for the error. You have to cast the error as NSError and then check, as such (assumes `error` is of type `Error?`):

`print((error! as NSError).userInfo)`

Comment: Do you mean it should literally have the string value `<TEAM_ID>.<APP_NAME>.<GROUP_NAME>` or we should replace the strings in angle brackets with their values (`<TEAM_ID>` etc)?

Answer (score 0):

My issue (same as above) was fixed by simply removing the$(AppIdentifierPrefix) string which is added to the entitlements file (if you use Xcode UI to add the keychain sharing group).

Comment: That can cause your app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but I'm not sure if it will work for everyone. Go to your target and click on the "signings & capabilities" tab. Click "+Capability" in the upper left and add "App Group". Add your group.member.project or whatever your keychain is there and delete the keychain capability. If you get an error regarding your entitlements file clear your build folder (Product > Clear Build Folder) and see if you can build it again!